# magento 2 - best practice to modified database structure

Tags: magento2

What is the best practice to extend / modified structure database?
Let say we want to add some field in `customer_entity` table,
is it violate the rules, or we have to add new table?

I didn't find any guide documentation about it.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to add new column into `customer_entity` table you must have to do InstallSchema operation.

Under your module Setup folder you have to define **InstallSchema.php** file.

just demo for *InstallSchema.php* file,

```
<?php

    namespace Package\Modulename\Setup;

    use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

    class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
    {
        public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
        {
            $installer = $setup;

            $installer->startSetup();
            $installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
                $installer->getTable('customer_entity'),
                'custom_field1',
                [
                    'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    'length'    => 128,
                    'unsigned' => true,
                    'nullable' => false,
                    'default' => '0',
                    'comment' => 'Custom field description'
                ]
            );
            //for second custom column
             $installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
                $installer->getTable('customer_entity'),
                'custom_field2',
                [
                    'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_SMALLINT,
                    'unsigned' => true,
                    'nullable' => false,
                    'default' => '0',
                    'comment' => 'pass your int value'
                ]
            );
            $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);

            $installer->endSetup();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Any idea how to copy table structure to new table using `InstallSchema.php`? @Rakesh

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 provide some classes which we can use for medified DB structure

**InstallSchema** – This class will execute when the module is installed to setup the database structure.

**InstallData** – This class will execute when the module is installed to initial the data for database table.

**UpgradeSchema** – This class will execute when the module is upgraded to setup the database structure.

**UpgradeData** – This class will execute when the module is upgraded to add/remove data from table.

Create the InstallSchema.php in the path app/code/[Vendor Name]/[Module Name]/Setup/InstallSchema.php

```
use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;


class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{

    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {

        $connection = $setup->getConnection();

            $column = [
                'type' => Table::TYPE_SMALLINT,
                'length' => 6,
                'nullable' => false,
                'comment' => 'Gift Charge Enable',
                'default' => '0'
            ];
            $connection->addColumn($setup->getTable('sales_order'), 'giftcharge_enable', $column);
        }
}
```

After adding this column in the setup file, run the following command:
php bin/magento setup:upgrade